# Script to print pass arguments to script

Tags: bash

I am using simple script to print the arguments. But not able to do so.

i am using cat command to add content to a file.

```
[root@cen06gst ~]# cat<<EOF>pass.sh
echo " you have passed me" $@
> EOF
```

But when i am seeing the file content again using cat , this is showing

```
[root@cen06gst ~]# cat pass.sh
echo " you have passed me"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cat only is a command line tool to concatenate and print to the screen, it doesn't modify the file. Read

```
man cat
```

If you want to run your script, run

```
./pass.sh argument
```

It is also good practice to start your script with a shebang:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Without it the system doesn't know what language to use to process the script.

Comment: Th.nks, now i am able to edit a file using VI editor and than i have run the script with success/